# Is there someway I can use an array or something else to reduce the Code here?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I have 7 Radio buttons and 5 check boxes. This is the code for if the first Radio button is selected and the first checkbox is selected, along with other. This only works if the first checkbox is checked. That means I have create this all over again for each check box. Which is all for the first Radio button if that makes sense. I realize doing so would just be a big mess of code. It'd work, but it'd be very very sloppy.

So, I was wondering if there is some way i can do this in an array or something else? I just want to shorten this up A LOT. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
if (radBrick.Checked)
{
    intBrick = 100000;
    intTotal = intBrick;

    if (chkBasketball.Checked)
    {
        intBasketball = 50000;
        intTotal = intBrick + intBasketball;

        if (chkFire.Checked)
        {
            intFire = 500;
            intTotal = intBrick + intBasketball + intFire;

            if (chkMarble.Checked)
            {
                intMarble = 20000;
                intTotal = intBrick + intBasketball + intFire + intMarble;

                if (chkSteel.Checked)
                {
                    intStain = 10000;
                    intTotal = intBrick + intBasketball + intFire + intStain + intMarble;

                    if (chkGarage.Checked)
                    {
                        intGarage = 5000;
                        intTotal = intBrick + intBasketball + intFire + intStain + intMarble + intGarage;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString("C");
}
```

Comment: Do the values change if one of the other radio buttons is selected?

Comment: Yes i want it for multiple radio buttons. and The only value that changes is the intBrick. everything else stays the same

Comment: There are something called CheckBoxList & RadioButtonList classes as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can - here is how:

```
int[] add = new[] {100000, 50000, 500, 20000, 10000, 50000};
bool[] check = new[] {radBrick.Checked, chkBasketball.Checked, chkFire.Checked, chkMarble.Checked, chkSteel.Checked, chkGarage.Checked};
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != add.Length ; i++) {
    if (check[i]) {
        sum += add[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The drawback here is the coupling between the `add[]` and `check[]` arrays become very fragile and depend on their indexes to to be an exact match. Alternatively, the checkboxes and their corresponding values could be placed into a dictionary and then summed. I've provided an [alternate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20448648/9664) with a dictionary.

Comment: @MetroSmurf This is never an issue when you hardcode both arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try transforming the Checked property into a 0 or 1 int value and multiply that times the fixed numbers and add everything up. More or less like this:

```
intBrick = 100000;
intBasketball = 50000;
intFire = 500;
intMarble = 20000;
intStain = 10000;
intGarage = 5000;

intTotal = (radBrick.Checked ? 1 : 0) * (intBrick +
           (chkBasketball.Checked ? 1 : 0) * (intBasketball +
           (chkFire.Checked ? 1 : 0) * (intFire +
           (chkFire.Checked ? 1 : 0) * (intMarble +
           (chkStain.Checked ? 1 : 0) * (intStain +
           (chkGarage.Checked ? 1 : 0) * intGarage)))));
```

Comment: A late thought is that none of the answers (including mine) correspond exactly to your nested ``if``s. They are more like independent sequential ``if``s. If you need nesting, you can use extra parenthesis    in my solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the nested parentheses to match the nested ``if``s in the question.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa, without a wider context (which only the OP has) it's hard to know if it's a good solution to the problem or not. Feel free to post an answer with your own suggestion.

Comment: Note that I didn't try to sound cocky or anything, but in my practice,  any chained ternary operatory usage I have ever encountered is a bad-bad idea. I've added my own approach that SHOULD match OP code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the requirement is to total all of the values with a checked state of true, you could place the CheckBox'es and their corresponding values into a dictionary and then use LINQ to sum the values:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<CheckBox, int>
{
    { chkBasketball, 50000 },
    { chkFire, 500 },
    { chkMarble, 20000 },
    { chkSteel, 10000 },
    { chkGarage, 5000 },
};

int sum = dic.Where( x => x.Key.Checked ).Sum( x => x.Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

```
int CalculateTotal (RadioButton radioButton, int currentTotal)
{
    if (radioButton.Checked)
        return 0;

    var elements = new[]
        {
            new
                {
                    CheckBoxButton = chkFire,
                    Value = 50000
                },

            new
                {
                    CheckBoxButton = chkMarbled,
                    Value = 500
                }

            // and so on
        };

    return currentTotal + elements.TakeWhile(x => x.CheckBoxButton.Checked).Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

and for each radio button you will use it as

```
  lblTotal.Text = CalculateTotal(chkBasketBall , 50000).ToString();
```

Comment: It's nice to see the variety of solutions that can be used to attack such a simple problem.